# Excel data validation by combining multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can i do excel validation formulas with multiple conditions?
I have one column where i want 
1) unique values 
2) All the values have to be 10 characters(leading zeroes allowed)
3) All have to be numbers

I can get unique values with the below formula:

```
=COUNTIF($G:$G,G2)=1
```

How do I add the other two conditions?

If i set the type as number, the leading zeroes are not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula
`=AND(COUNTIF(G:G,G2)=1,LEN(G2)=10,ISNUMBER(VALUE(G2)))`

1. `COUNTIF(G:G,G2)=1` checks the unique condition.
2. `LEN(G2)=10` checks the length, including leading zeros i.e., number stored in text format.
3. `ISNUMBER(VALUE(G2))` checks the value of the cell.

`AND` condition ensures all the above are met.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're only dealing with integers:

```
=AND(COUNTIF($G:$G, G2)=1, IFERROR(LEN(TEXT(G2, "0000000000"))=10, FALSE))
```